# Running eight threads in a particular order until termination

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've a core 2 duo processor.

I want to create and run eight threads(that have no shared data in between them) such that in any given time all eight will run once where thread 1 and thread 2  will run at the same time and if thread 1 and thread 2 can't run simultaneously by the processor I want priority be given to thread 1 so that thread 1 will run before thread 2.

Similarly thread 3 and 4  can run concurrently but if thread 3 and thread 4 can't run at the same time I want thread 3 to execute before thread 4 and not before thread 1 and 2 and not after thread 5 and 6 and thread 7 and thread 8.

Same for thread 5 and thread 6, thread 7 and thread 8.

After all 8 threads have finish their tasks the 8 threads will run again and again in the above given order until termination.

How can achieve this using c++ and visual studio 2008 on Windows 7?

Is it possible to implement this with c++?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use threads in this way? That's pretty much exactly what they're **not** there for.

Comment: "1 and 2 can run simultaneously", but "thread 2 has to run after thread 1"? How does that make sense?

Comment: @Roman R. No. I've eight ps3eye cameras. I want to use threading mechanism to capture images from them where any two can run concurrently.

Comment: @jalf Sorry for the confusion but what I meant is if thread 1 and thread 2 can't run concurrently thread 2 has to run after thread 1.

Comment: @mvr950: maybe you need to put this onto post, why you are doing this in first place. It is not quite clear how this threading game is going to be helpful.

Comment: "thread 1 and thread 2 can't run concurrently thread 2", but "I want to use threading mechanism to capture images from them where any two can run concurrently"? It still doesn't make sense. Which thread **can** run concurrently, and when?

Comment: @jalf I've a core 2 duo processor so any two threads can run at the same time. After creating 8 threads if thread 1 and thread 2 can't run at the same time I want thread 2 to execute after thread 1.

Comment: *But you just said that thread 1 and thread 2 are not allowed to run at the same time*. You're contradicting yourself. You seem to want your threads to *both* run sequentially, one after another, in a specific order, and at the same time have them run concurrently?

Comment: And, it is questionable that 8 USB cameras can operate in a minimal stable way at all, due to limited bandwidth.

Comment: Please reword your question. It is not exactly clear what you want to do. if "After creating 8 threads if thread 1 and thread 2 can't run at the same time I want thread 2 to execute after thread 1" this is what you are trying to do, it is not possible.

Comment: @jalf Sorry if I said that. After creating threads it's not guaranteed that any two threads will run simultaneously on a dual core processor. So if two threads don't run simultaneously I want priority be given such that thread 1(created first) will run first and thread 2(created second) will always run after thread 1.

Comment: Okay. I suggest you edit your question to actually explain *that*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you want is not what you are asking for.  What is the desired behaviour and what is your actual problem?  A guess would be that you want your system to generate frames from the cameraas at the same rate & so you want a rendezvous/barrier so that you can do whatever it is you have to with a complete set of frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of wrangling to actually get the question out of you, here's the version I'm going to try to answer:

> After creating threads it's not guaranteed that any two threads will run simultaneously on a dual core processor. So if two threads don't run simultaneously I want priority be given such that thread 1(created first) will run first and thread 2(created second) will always run after thread 1.

And luckily, the answer to *that* is fairly simple. Your program doesn't know which threads are run when. The OS doesn't tell you when it starts and stops a thread, so you can't code any kind of "is thread 1 running? If not, I'll pause and let that run" check.

But you can set the threads to have different priorities. That indicates to the OS which ones it should schedule for execution. Give your threads a gradually decreasing priority (so thread 1 has a high priority, thread 2 one step lower and so on), and you'll have made something that kind of approximates what you want. On Windows, this might actually work out fairly well, since Windows always tries to pick the highest prioritized threads/processes available. Linux will try to ensure that all threads get *some* execution time, but will simply give *more* to higher prioritized ones.

And of course, messing with priorities like this also affects how your program is scheduled in relation to everything else running on the PC. You're really trying to go about this the wrong way, and the saner solution would be to simply find another scheme for parallelizing this.

Comment: 'find another scheme for parallelizing this' - yes, one that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can control the order of execution of threads. Once threads are created, it is up to the OS to do the scheduling for you. All you can do is wait for the threads to finish in your parent thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any mechanism that I can use to force the threads to wait for all 8 threads to complete and then start again?

Comment: Yes. Every C++ compiler gives us a mechanism to do that. For ex., in Posix threads, we have a function pthread_join(...) which waits for the thread you pass in the function param to complete. Since you have 8 threads, you can call the function in a for loop.

Comment: Not true, you can certainly block threads until some condition in another thread is satisfied

Answer (score 0):

What? You want to use run thread 1, then thread 2 ...

Dont use threads. Use a while loop and call:

```
While(1)
{
   foo1();
   foo2();
   foo3();
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Yes I can do that. But I want any 2 threads to run at the same time.

Comment: @mvr950 then tell us *which* two threads are allowed to run at the same time

Comment: @jalf What I meant by thread 1, thread 2 ....thread 8 is that thread 1 is the thread that captures image from camera 1, thread 2 from camera 2, thread 3 from camera 3 ... thread 8 from camera 8. I want the thread 1 and thread 2 to run concurrently, thread 3 and 4 concurrently ... and thread 7 and thread 8 at the same time.